# Charting tool similar to Google Visualization

Tags: javascript, charts, visualization, d3.js

I need to include a dashboard in a JavaScript application I am building. The [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) would provide all the features I am looking for, except that I need a tool that works without internet access and could be embedded in my application.

My main requirements:

- Standard pie, bar and line charts
- hover and onclick behaviors
- data aggregation: sum, average, etc. (like Google datatables)
- time scale with time range filters
- nice to have: heat maps, gauges, geo maps, Gantt, etc.

Alternately, I'd be interested in recommendations on a graphing toolkit that would be a good starting point. I've read good things about d3.js, but there is not much documentation around. I haven't even found which browsers d3 supports (I need IE 7).

Comment: If you are looking for D3 documentation, try https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference. There's lots more tutorials and such linked from the wiki, too.

Comment: @mbostock thx. That's where I looked, but I didn't find answers to simple questions like which browsers are supported, or a list of plugins/modules.

Comment: See the README for browser support. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/README.md We haven't formalized plugin modules yet, but there are lots of examples you can crib from on the wiki home page.

Comment: thx. Any recommendation for older browsers that don't support svg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dojox charting is rich in features, open-source and extensible, works cross browser, and supports multiple rendering engines: svg, canvas, vml - it is being actively evolved and has come a long way since its introduction. I have used it successfully in several projects.

High Charts and Fusion charts also now offer JS based charting

Raphael JS is also good for lightweight charting needs -

You may want to weigh the features/richness with performance, open-source/extensibility and other factors to make the choice - good news is that there are many libraries out there now :-)

Comment: Thx, all look like great options. dojox looks very interesting, I am wondering why it never shows up in library reviews. I hadn't heard about it before.

Comment: perhaps because it is not marketed as much, it being an open-source framework. Also imo only in the past year or so has it really become very rich (cool)- it is very flexible so you can extend, plugin your own custom functionality, and even contribute to the community -

Answer (score 1):

There are some different frameworks for it, for example:

- [flot](https://github.com/flot/flot) for jQuery
- [g.raphael](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael) for Raphaël
- [Highcharts JS](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com) as framework for Javascript

But there are many more. Try searching and look for a framework/plugin that fits your needs.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me that the solutions you mention "only" do charting, they don't have the data aggregation capabilities needed in a dashboard (which are available with Google).

Comment: Yes you are right, Highcharts will only draw whats given to it (except when grouping daily points into weeks in datetime charts http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#plotOptions-series-dataGrouping--approximation). This probably goes for FusionCharts as well as they bundle highcharts in their solution, but I'm not 100% certain on this.

Answer (score 1):

The [FusionCharts Suite](http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/) seems to be the best fit for your needs.

- Column, bar, pie charts - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#column-and-bar
- Hover and on-click behaviours - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/features/#interactive-legend & http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/features/#informative-tool-tips
- Data aggregation - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#zoom-line
- Time scale charts - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/features/#self-updating-charts
- Heat map charts - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#heat-map-chart
- Visually editable charts - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#visually-editable-charts
- Gauges with real-time capabilities - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#gauges
- Funnels - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#funnel-chart
- Pyramid charts - http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#pyramid-chart

It has exhaustive documentation too - http://docs.fusioncharts.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just to contribute to the discussion I suggest you check out [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/).

Their JavaScript Charting library is quite robust, actively developed and supported, well documented. IE7 is supported as well.

The [JavaScript Stock Chart](http://www.amcharts.com/stock/) product provides most of the features you mentioned like datapoint aggregation. It's even dynamic based on the zoom scope.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at InfoCaptor Dashboards http://www.infocaptor.com

It can be self hosted and embeddable with other applications. The backend is PHP and it is completely javascript/html5 based charting engine.

Suppports all of the following requirements

- Standard pie, bar and line charts - Out of box
- hover and onclick behaviors - out of box
- data aggregation: sum, average, etc. (like  Google datatables) -
  provides connectors to all SQL database and
- including Google spreadsheet time scale with time range filters -
  Dashboard prompts/parameters and filters nice to have: heat maps,
- gauges, geo maps, Gantt, etc. - contains Gantts and variety of Gauges

It does not have maps but you can build the charts using jvectormaps or other map api and the custom html widget within the dashboard.

Hope this helps